# Swift 3 - Stop View Unwraping itself when segue is performed

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, segue

Good Day

I hope your are all well.

I have this problem where I have 1 view that can be accessed by two different ViewControllers. Both ViewControllers are embedded in a navigation controller.

Ok for a better understanding we have 3 views that are in a V shape 
(View 1 - Left) (View 2 - Right) (View 3 - Middle)

Both view 1 and view 2 are embedded in a navigation controller.

When a segue from view 1 - view 3 is performed multiple times it works no problems.

When a segue from view 2 - view 3 is performed it does this paging animation through all the previous segues that where called on in. In my terms I call it "Unwrapping". The amount of segues performed to it from View 2 is the amount of times it unwraps. Views 1 segues dont effect the number of unwraps and doesnt display unwraps from view 1 - view 3 if i do multiple segues to it.

Does anyone know a way to stop this happening. The views animation is from right to left when unwrapping.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Please upload a demo video

Comment: Good Day- Thanks for the reply unfortunately I cannot do that my company has made me sign a confidentiality document

Comment: You can make a demo app with the same view controller structure as the original one and share the video. Because the question is a bit confusing